# How can I combine a line and scatter on same plotly chart?

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

The two separate charts created from data.frame work correctly when created using the R plotly package.
However,
I am not sure how to combine them into one (presumably with the add_trace function)

```
df <- data.frame(season=c("2000","2000","2001","2001"), game=c(1,2,1,2),value=c(1:4))

plot_ly(df, x = game, y = value, mode = "markers", color = season)
plot_ly(subset(df,season=="2001"), x = game, y = value, mode = "line")
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two main ways you can do this with plotly, make a `ggplot` and convert to a `plotly` object as @MLavoie suggests OR as you suspected by using `add_trace` on an existing `plotly` object (see below).

```
library(plotly)

#data
df <- data.frame(season=c("2000","2000","2001","2001"), game=c(1,2,1,2),value=c(1:4))

#Initial scatter plot
p <- plot_ly(df, x = game, y = value, mode = "markers", color = season)

#subset of data
df1 <- subset(df,season=="2001")

#add line
p %>% add_trace(x = df1$game, y = df1$value, mode = "line")
```

Answer (score 11):

The answer given by @LukeSingham does not work anymore with `plotly 4.5.2`. 
You have to start with an "empty" `plot_ly()` and then to add the traces:

```
df1 <- data.frame(season=c("2000","2000","2001","2001"), game=c(1,2,1,2), value=c(1:4))
df2 <- subset(df, season=="2001")

plot_ly() %>% 
  add_trace(data=df1, x = ~game, y = ~value, type="scatter", mode="markers") %>% 
  add_trace(data=df2, x = ~game, y = ~value, type="scatter", mode = "lines")
```

Answer (score 5):

here is a way to do what you want, but with ggplot2 :-) You can change the background, line, points color as you want.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
    df_s <- df[c(3:4), ]

    p <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x = game, y = value, color = season)) +
      geom_point(size = 4) +
      geom_line(data=df_s, aes(x = game, y = value, color = season))

    (gg <- ggplotly(p))
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the ggplot option. I tend to like going native - as plotly does offer plenty of options - but a def +1