# Layered ScatterD3 plots?

Tags: r, plot, layer, pca, scatter

Is it possible to overlay multiple layers of ScatterD3 plots on top of one another?  I haven't been able to find this anywhere in either the vignettes or searching StackExchange/Google.

I'm curious, since folks have been able to make [PCA Vector Loading](https://onsocialtrends.org/politics/state.html#scatterd3) plots using ScatterD3.  If one could overlay this on top of another plot with the points (akin to what's possible with `ggplot2` or `ggvis` layers), you could have a gorgeous and interactive PCA plot.  Additionally, you might be able to outline points (since point stroke currently isn't an option).

Does anyone have any insight or workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but more difficult. I would recommend using `plotly` package. You'll be able to use the View tab in the RStudio and more easily examine your 3D scatter by rotating. The color scheme is also easier to add [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34444906/how-can-i-combine-a-line-and-scatter-on-same-plotly-chart) attempts to tackle a similar, though not identical. A good (free) tutorial for `plotly` can be found [here through DataCamp](https://www.datacamp.com/community/open-courses/plotly-tutorial-plotly-and-r#gs.kgQOIP0).

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question; I'm asking about the ScatterD3 package, not scatterplot3d.  Confusing how similar the names are, I know.

Comment: Yes, I did misunderstand your question, and sorry about that. Since `ScatterD` utilizes `ggplot2` and therefore `grid` graphics, maybe you could seek to make changes to R grid? This might overcomplicate your task but that's where I would go if I you really need to get it done...

Answer (score 0):

[Question answered here](https://github.com/juba/scatterD3/issues/62) thanks to the author of ScatterD3.  To generate a full PCA plot, you need to redefine the dataframe being plotted like so:

```
library(FactoMineR)
library (ScatterD3)

out<-PCA(iris[,1:4],scale.unit = TRUE, graph=FALSE)
    cc1<-data.frame(out$ind$coord)
    cc2<-data.frame(out$var$coord)

points <- data.frame(x = cc1$Dim.1, 
                     y = cc1$Dim.2,
                     color = iris$Species,
                     lab = row.names(iris), 
                     type = rep("point", 150))

arrows <- data.frame(x = cc2$Dim.1, 
                     y = cc2$Dim.2, 
                     color = "Blue",
                     lab = row.names(cc2), 
                     type = rep("arrow", 4))

data1 <- rbind(points, arrows)

scatterD3(data1, x = x, y = y,
          lab = lab, type_var = data1$type, col_var = color)
```