# Add a line that indicates the average value of an axis in a plotly scatterplot

Tags: r, plotly

I would like to know if it is possible to add a horizontal line with a hover text ability like the one in the screenshot below which will indicate the average value of the y-axis

```
library(plotly)

p <- plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length)
```

[image]

Comment: [how-can-i-combine-a-line-and-scatter-on-same-plotly-chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34444906/how-can-i-combine-a-line-and-scatter-on-same-plotly-chart)

Comment: that works but how can I put hover text on this line?